# How can I make the button at the end download the selected file

Tags: php, html, download

The table shows everything perfect with the dl button but when I click on it nothing happens. When inspecting the element it only detected part of the files names on the htm code however on the table it appears complete.

```
<?php
            // Opens directory
            $myDirectory=opendir("Facturas");

            // Gets each entry
            while($entryName=readdir($myDirectory)) {
              $dirArray[]=$entryName;
            }

            // Finds extensions of files
            function findexts ($filename) {
              $filename=strtolower($filename);
              $exts=split("[/\\.]", $filename);
              $n=count($exts)-1;
              $exts=$exts[$n];
              return $exts;
            }

            // Closes directory
            closedir($myDirectory);

            // Counts elements in array
            $indexCount=count($dirArray);

            // Sorts files
            sort($dirArray);

            // Loops through the array of files
            for($index=0; $index < $indexCount; $index++) {

              // Allows ./?hidden to show hidden files
              if($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']=="hidden")
              {$hide="";
              $ahref="./";
              $atext="Hide";}
              else
              {$hide=".";
              $ahref="./?hidden";
              $atext="Show";}
              if(substr("$dirArray[$index]", 0, 1) != $hide) {

              // Gets File Names
              $name=$dirArray[$index];
              $namehref=$dirArray[$index];

              // Gets Extensions 
              $extn=findexts($dirArray[$index]); 

              // Gets file size 
              $size=number_format(filesize($dirArray[$index]));

              // Gets Date Modified Data
              $modtime=date("M j Y g:i A", filemtime($dirArray[$index]));
              $timekey=date("YmdHis", filemtime($dirArray[$index]));

              // Prettifies File Types, add more to suit your needs.
              switch ($extn){
                case "png": $extn="PNG Image"; break;
                case "jpg": $extn="JPEG Image"; break;
                case "svg": $extn="SVG Image"; break;
                case "gif": $extn="GIF Image"; break;
                case "ico": $extn="Windows Icon"; break;
                case "txt": $extn="Text File"; break;
                case "log": $extn="Log File"; break;
                case "htm": $extn="HTML File"; break;
                case "php": $extn="PHP Script"; break;
                case "js": $extn="Javascript"; break;
                case "css": $extn="Stylesheet"; break;
                case "pdf": $extn="PDF Document"; break;
                case "zip": $extn="ZIP Archive"; break;
                case "bak": $extn="Backup File"; break;

                default: $extn=strtoupper($extn)." File"; break;
              }

              // Separates directories
              if(is_dir($dirArray[$index])) {
                $extn="&lt;Directory&gt;"; 
                $size="&lt;Directory&gt;"; 
                $class="dir";
              } else {
                $class="file";
              }

              // Cleans up . and .. directories 
              if($name=="."){$name=". (Current Directory)"; $extn="&lt;System Dir&gt;";}
              if($name==".."){$name=".. (Parent Directory)"; $extn="&lt;System Dir&gt;";}

              // Print 'em
              print("
              <tr class='$class'>
                <td>$name</td>
                <td>$extn</td>
                <td>$size</td>
                <td sorttable_customkey='$timekey'>$modtime</td>
                <td <a href=/Facturas/$name$extn' download> <button> DL </button> </a> </td>
              </tr>");
              }
            }
          ?>
```

Comment: at first glance it looks like you've missed a single quote mark on this line

    <td <a href=/Facturas/$name$extn' download> <button> DL </button> </a> </td>

Comment: also the td needs to be closed on the DL button line <td> <a....